# How to call PHP function using jQuery ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a file called myfunctions.php where I have a lot of functions, like

```
function sendForm(){
    //save form
}
function fn2(){
 //do something
}
 // Other functions ...
```

and the jquery code,

```
$.ajax({
    url: "myfunctions.php",
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    data: {key1: "value1", key2: "value2", key3: "value3"},
    complete: function(){
        //completado
        alert("complete");
    }
});
```

I need call specific function in this file; for example `sendForm()`. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In PHP

```
<?php
// create a list of approved function calls
$approved_functions = array('sendForm','fn2');

// check the $_GET['function'] and see if it matches an approved function
if(in_array($_GET['function'], $approved_functions))
{
    // call the approved function
    $_GET['function']();
}

function sendForm(){
    //save form
}
function fn2(){
 //do something
}
```

In AJAX

```
// specify which function to call
url: "myfunctions.php?function=sendForm",
```

Comment: But I going to do this for more the 50 function... Other suggestion?

Comment: No, I recommend no other approach. If you are willing to give up the security and integrity of your web application then you can just skip the `$approved_functions` checking and execute whatever `$_GET['function']` has inside of it. Just call `$_GET['function']();` but just know that you will be subject to unwanted function injection like this `url: "myfunctions.php?function=phpinfo",`

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajax({
    //...
    data: {key1: "value1", key2: "value2", key3: "value3", type:0},
    //...
});
```

`myfunctions.php`:

```
<?php
//...
if (!isset($_POST['type'])) { /* return something */ exit; }
$type = $_POST['type'];
if ($type == 0)
{
    function1();
} else if ($type == 1) {
    function2();
} //etc.
//...
?>
```

Comment: Aren't there another way?

Comment: @omixam No, this is the safest and most standard way.